# put contents of span inside href

Tags: php, html

I have a span whose content (a record #, eg: 'record12345') is generated via javascript. I want to include that record # in an href.

My goal is :

```
<a href="user/record12345">Link</a>
```

If I just call the `span` like so, I get the record # as expected:

```
<span id="exampleId"></span>
```

But I can't get it to work inside an href. Here are some things I've tried:

```
<a href='<?php echo "user/<span id='exampleId'></span>" ; ?>'>Link</a>
<a href='user/<?php echo "<span id='exampleId'></span>" ; ?>'>Link</a>
<a href="user/<?php echo '<span id="exampleId"></span>" ;?>">Link</a>
<a href="user/<span id='exampleId'></span>">Link</a>
```

Comment: *"I am lost and hungry and alone... please help!"* - I can give you a sandwich, but I can't help you in regards to "keeping you company".

Comment: hah! what about the "lost" part...?

Comment: I can drum up some GPS related code, will that help? ;)

Comment: I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding - client-side and server-side code **do not** mix well.

Comment: You're doing something with javascript, please paste that code

Comment: But seriously, if you want to get an ID inside an `href`, have you tried using a variable? I.e.: `$user=123;` then `user/$user` type of thing.

Comment: Is this question a troll?

Comment: Dude, I hope you're joking or someone stole your account, you have 1k+ rep.

Comment: @ShawnTaylor why don't you make an empty div with an id and once your JavaScript executes you fill in with the links and content altogether rather than just editing?

Comment: Here's a bit of fun (*yes, it's amusing*) I had while having lunch; yeah, I eat late. (*So, how's that sandwich? Not too much mustard I hope?*) `<span id="<?php echo "user/$user"; ?>"><a href="<?php echo "user/$user"; ?>">Link to user ID <?php echo $user; ?></a></span>`

**HTML source:** `<span id="123"><a href="user/123">Link to user ID 123</a></span>`

Comment: @formerlyknownasme SamDufel, not a joke, not a troll. My rep is all based on html/css/ and specifically Bootstrap, or otherwise my usual ability to cobble stuff together. I'm working with someone else's code, and am learning by "if I do this, what happens?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that PHP nonsense.

Put this Javascript somewhere

```
document.onload = function(){
// Get the inner stuff from the span
var url = document.getElementById('exampleId').innerHTML;
var link = document.getElementById('myLink');
link.setAttribute("href",url);
}
```

Then assuming your span has the link inside of it, and the `<a>` tag has an `id='myLink'` this will work.

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GUhj3/3/)...

Comment: A version of this did it for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```
$('span').click(function() {
    window.location.href="user/"+$(this).attr('id');
});
```

what you are attempting to do above is inject client side code back into the server script